# upload file with vichuploaderbundle symfony api plateform

Tags: symfony6, vichuploaderbundle

my problem is when i upload video with vichuploaderbundle in api plateform symfony , postman return an error , it makes the value of the other fields null . Help me please, Thanks

I try to make a api with api plateform symfony6